# Headings and paragraphs in Asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say I have a data of posts with attributes Title and Content
Now I want to display Title in h1 and Content in p
how do I use a for/while loop. to generate these tags using c# Asp.net
So its like this

## Heading1

Content

## heading2

content again

and it keeps on going.. 
??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to have understood, but you mean that you fetch some kind of data, and you want to display in that way? You should probably use a Listview, defining an ItemTemplate inside it, and assigning the data to the DataSource property.

For example, in your .aspx file

```
 <asp:ListView ID="LvPost" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="LvPost_ItemDataBound">
     <ItemTemplate>
     <h1><asp:Literal id="title" runat="server"></h1>
     <p><asp:Literal id="content" runat="server"></p>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

Then, in your LvPost_ItemDataBound method something like

```
var postItem= e.Item.DataItem as YourPostClass;
var h1Text = e.Item.FindControl("title") as Literal;
var pText= e.Item.FindControl("content") as Literal;
h1Text.Text=postItem.Title;
pText.Text = postItem.Content;
```

Finally, don't forget to bind the data to the listview, (ex: in the PageLoad)

```
LvPost.DataSource = <List of YourPostClass>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly how you have your data, but something like this might work. Put a literal on your page where you'd like the data to appear, then use code like this:

```
string[] headings = {"Heading 1", "Heading 2", "Heading 3"};
string[] paragraphs = {"Content", "content again","Content even again!"};

literal1.Text = "";
for (int i=0; i<headings.Length;i++)
{
    literal1.Text = string.Format("{0}<h1>{1}</h1><p>{2}</p>{3}", literal1.Text, HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(headings[i]), HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(paragraphs[i]), Environment.Newline);
}
```

Note that I'm using `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode` to encode the strings. If you wish to include HTML markup inside the content (for example if  `paragraphs[0] == "<b>Content</b>`"), then remove this method.

If you prefer a `List<T>` and container class instead, this code might be more appropriate:

```
private class Content
{
    public string Heading { get; set; };
    public string Paragraph { get; set; };
}

private List<Content> _content = new List<Content>();

private void CreateContent()
{
    _content.Add(new Content {Heading = "Heading 1", Paragraph = "Content"});
    _content.Add(new Content {Heading = "Heading 2", Paragraph = "More Content"});
    _content.Add(new Content {Heading = "Heading 3", Paragraph = "Even More Content"});

   literal1.Text = "";
   foreach (Content c in _content)
   {
       literal1.Text = string.Format("{0}<h1>{1}</h1><p>{2}</p>{3}", literal1.Text, HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(c.Heading), HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode(c.Paragraph), Environment.Newline);
   }
}
```